# Updating an external dictionary automatically in python

Tags: python, dictionary, authentication

Note: this project is really insecure to cyberattacks, however it is a mock service and holds no real sensitive information

I am doing a mini project where users can login and create a password. as my knowledge is only with python, I am storing the usernames and passwords in an external dictionary, then allowing the users to add their usernames and passwords which then update the other python file with the dictionary. however, the file isn't getting updated.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import users_details

print("welcome new user, here you can register an account!")
desired_username = str(input("please enter your desired username: "))

if desired_username in users_details.user_details.keys():
    print("you already have an account, please consider logging in")
else:
    print("this username is unique! please input a password")
    print("password has no limitations, but keep it secure!")

    desired_password = str(input("input your password here: "))
    print("we are currently adding your details to our dictionary, and creating you a balance!")

    users_details.user_details[desired_username] = desired_password
    users_details.user_balance[desired_username] = 1000

    print("your account has been registered to the network! ")
```

Comment: Give an upvote if my answer satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The file will not get updated as when you take username and password it gets updated to dictionary which is presently in memory. You have to write to that python file which contains your dictionary.
For your project you should do is add a write statement at last of your program like this:

```
else:
...
with open("user_details.py", "w") as f:
    f.write("user_details = "+ str(user_details.user_details))
```

This will definitely update your dictionary after updation in dictionary